# Is there a way to go to reference when inspecting an excel formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have this in a formula:

```
Input!$J$3
```

Is there a shortcut or some quick way for me to navigate to that location?

Comment: no there isn't. Starting to edit the formula (click on it in the formula bar, or press F2) shows you the referenced cells, but there is no way to jump that. Also you can toggle formulas - trace precedents to draw an arrow to referenced cells.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double click inside your formula.
2. Select the formula part that contains the address of your reference cell. (`Input!$J$3` in your case)
3. Press <kbd>F5</kbd> which will bring up the `Go To` dialogue box and press OK.
4. This will take you to the reference cell in the related sheet.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Highlight the cell and press CTRL+[ to jump to the referenced cell. On cells with multiple references it will jump to the first reference.

Comment: Can you go into more detail on what this actually does? Your answer is at risk of being removed. Please see [answer] and take our [tour].

Comment: If you press `Ctrl + [` on a cell with a formula, for example =A1+A2, it will jump to and highlight the cells in that formula.